# Sort values of a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have over 9000 data attributes in a dictionary. Simple version looks like this:

```
test = {1092268: [81, 90], 524292: [80, 80], 892456: [88, 88]}
```

They are gene id's with two values inside a list. What I want is to end up with multiple dictionaries that contain all the id's with values above or under a certain value. So in this example lets say I want to end up with three dictionaries, one contains the id's and values that are both below 85, the other both above 85 and the last with the first value under 85 and the second above 85. So I would end up with this:

```
testabove = { 892456: [88, 88]}
```

and

```
testbelow = { 524292: [80, 80]}
```

and

```
testboth = { {1092268: [81, 90]}
```

I have no idea how to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple to do that using a dictionary comprehension

```
>>> testabove = {i:j for i,j in test.items() if j[0]>85 and j[1] > 85}
>>> testbelow = {i:j for i,j in test.items() if j[0]<85 and j[1] < 85}
>>> testboth = {i:j for i,j in test.items() if i not in testabove and i not in testbelow}
>>> testabove
{892456: [88, 88]}
>>> testbelow
{524292: [80, 80]}
>>> testboth
{1092268: [81, 90]}
```

As Marein mentions below in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972065/sort-values-of-a-list-in-a-dictionary#comment48064190_29972153), the other way to do it

```
>>> test = {1092268: [81, 90], 524292: [80, 80], 892456: [88, 88]}
>>> testabove = {i:j for i,j in test.items() if all(x>85 for x in j)}
>>> testbelow = {i:j for i,j in test.items() if all(x<85 for x in j)}
>>> testabove
{892456: [88, 88]}
>>> testbelow
{524292: [80, 80]}
```

This uses [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function

*Comparison*

```
$ python -m timeit "test = {1092268: [81, 90], 524292: [80, 80], 892456: [88, 88]};testabove = {i:j for i,j in test.items() if all(x>85 for x in j)}"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.29 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "test = {1092268: [81, 90], 524292: [80, 80], 892456: [88, 88]};testabove = {i:j for i,j in test.items() if j[0]>85 and j[1] > 85}"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.99 usec per loop
```

As you can see, the straight forward way is faster than using `all`.

Comment: You could use `min(j) > 85` as a condition for `testabove` and analogous for `testbelow`. Or possibly `all(x>85 for x in j)` which is faster in the negative case.

Comment: @Marein I think that the straightforward way is the best because it requires less explanation :)  But yeah, that is a good idea. Thanks

Comment: @Marein: Nice ideas. Although the `all`-based solution short-circuits I suspect that min / max would be faster, since they're working at C speed. Anybody feel like doing some timeit tests... ?

Comment: Indeed I was a bit hasty in saying it is faster, it might not be depending on the implementation.

Comment: I bet `all` would definitely win if the lists were bigger, if they short-circuited frequently enough. But in the OP's application they'll only ever have two elements (and I suspect they ought to be tuples, rather than lists).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that should be faster for a large amount of data, because it builds all three dictionaries in one iteration.

```
def compare_both(xs,pivot):
 if xs[0] < pivot and xs[1] < pivot: return -1
 if xs[0] > pivot and xs[1] > pivot: return 1
 return 0

def sort_dict(d,pivot):
  dicts = [{},{},{}]
  for key,value in d.items():
    dicts[compare_both(value,pivot)+1][key] = value
  return dicts
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight-forward solution:

```
tmp = testboth, testabove, testbelow = {}, {}, {}
for k, v in test.items():
    tmp[(v[0] > 85 < v[1]) - (v[0] < 85 > v[1])][k] = v
```

It's also faster than Bhargav's solution, judging by tests with random input of appropriate size. Test and results:

```
from random import *
test = {key: [randrange(170), randrange(170)] for key in sample(range(10000000), 9500)}
from timeit import timeit
print 'Bhargav', timeit(lambda: Bhargav(), number=100)
print 'Stefan', timeit(lambda: Stefan(), number=100)

Bhargav 1.87454111948
Stefan 1.2636884789
```

Two more variations, not sure what I like best.

```
testboth, testabove, testbelow = tmp = {}, {}, {}
for k, (a, b) in test.items():
    tmp[(a > 85 < b) - (a < 85 > b)][k] = [a, b]

for k, v in test.items():
    a, b = v
    tmp[(a > 85 < b) - (a < 85 > b)][k] = v
```

Timings for these are about 1.7 and 1.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic options. One if you need an iterable and one if you need a more permanent data structure. The more permanent solution is to initialize all three target dictionaries, then iterate through your source dict and sort them where appropriate.

```
target_dicts = {'aboveabove':{}, 'belowbelow':{}, 'belowabove':{}}
for k,v in src_dict.items():
    first = 'above' if v[0] > 85 else 'below'
    second = 'above' if v[1] > 85 else 'below'
    result = first+second  # 'aboveabove', 'belowbelow', etc...
    if result in target_dicts:
        target_dicts[result][k] = v
```

This will populate your `target_dicts` dictionaries appropriately. But maybe you don't need to use them all? You might just need an iterator, rather than actually rebuilding those in memory. Let's use a filter instead!

```
target_iterators = {
    'aboveabove': filter(
        lambda k: all(v > 85 for v in src_dict[k]), src_dict),
    'belowbelow': filter(
        lambda k: all(v <= 85 for v in src_dict[k]), src_dict),
    'belowabove': filter(
        lambda k: src_dict[k][0] <= 85 and src_dict[k][1] > 85, src_dict)}
```